# Levinson Recursion for Non Square Toeplitz Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, linear-system, convolution

Given a rectangular [Toeplitz Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) $ H $, how could one solve:

$$ y = H x $$

For instance, $ H $ can be Linear Convolution Matrix of the filter $ h $:

$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
{h}_{1} & 0 & 0 & \ldots &  & 0 \\ 
{h}_{2} & {h}_{1} & 0 & \ldots &  & 0 \\ 
{h}_{m} & \ldots & {h}_{1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
0 & {h}_{m} & \ldots & {h}_{1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
\vdots &  & \ddots &  &  & \vdots \\ 
0 & \ldots & {h}_{m} & {h}_{m - 1} & \ldots & {h}_{1} \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & {h}_{m} & \ldots & {h}_{2} \\
\vdots &  & \ddots &  &  & \vdots \\ 
0 & \ldots &  & 0 & \ldots & {h}_{m} \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Which is clearly not square.
In the general case it would be generated by:

```matlab
numRows = 10; %<! Or any other number
numCols = 20; %<! Or any other number
vR = randn(numRows, 1);
vC = randn(numCols, 1);
mH = toeplitz(vC, vR);
```

Since the Matrix is not square, I'm after the least squares solution:

$$ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| H x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

I have implemented the [Levinson Recursion](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/LevinsonRecursion) for the square case yet I'd like to know if there is an extension to it.

At the moment the trick I use for this specific case it to partition the matrix and data for a subset of square Toeplitz Matrices and use the algorithm I implemented.
I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: What are you trying to compute here? In the square case, a (nonsingular) linear system has a unique solution, so I assume that this solution is your 'target'. In the non-square case, there are either zero or infinite solutions, so it is not clear what this algorithm should compute in the first place.

Comment: You may think of it as the Least Squares Solution in the case of a Non Square Toeplitz Matrix.